# Do nuclear reaction cross sections depend on the angle between incident beam and target-crystal?

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

Shouldn't the absorption rate of a  beam of particles strongly depend on the angle between the beam and the target material's crystal-axis (if the target material is a monocrystal)? At certain angles, all the nuclei will be stacked behind each other, offering a very small cross section, whereas other orientations will expose all of the nuclei without any shadowing. However, I don't see any mention of this in cross-section tables, so I guess it doesn't matter. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your target is a film $10^{-2}$ mm thick. Nuclei are about $10^{-14}$ m in diamater at most. This means that the alignment of the beam with the target would have to be $10^{-9}$ radians, which is not possible with realistic beam optics. Even if your beam optics were that perfect, the perfect parallelism would be destroyed by scattering once the beam entered the target.

Comment: @annav Interesting link - I was thinking about nuclear cross sections. But the Muon effect is interesting.

Comment: I also believe that the thermal vibration amplitudes of the nuclei in the lattice will be several orders of magnitude larger than the diameter of the nucleus.

Comment: @SebastianHenckel: Good point. That would reduce the precision required from the beam optics, but would also attenuate the effect by the square of the same factor.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed something similar to what you describe, the so-called blocking effect (or shadow effect) - http://www.nupecc.org/iai2001/report/C3.pdf , http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Blocking+Effect

EDIT (08/24/2013): Let me expand on my answer. There are at least two important effects related to propagation of charged high energy particles (or, in particular, nuclei) through a crystal: blocking effect and channeling effect. I cannot describe these effects in detail here - you can google them. What's important, this propagation strongly depends on the angles between the velocity of the particles and the crystal axes. This dependence is mostly caused by the Coulomb interaction between the particles and the atoms (electrons and nuclei) of the crystal. However, due to the modified pattern of propagation, the conditions of nuclear reactions of the particles with nuclei in the crystals can also be modified - see, e.g., Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research B 99 (1995) 440-443 (http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CC4QFjABOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F235224869_Nuclear_reaction_channeling%2Ffile%2Fd912f510926a532e2c.pdf&ei=t5QYUumYJsiJ2AXf8YCQBw&usg=AFQjCNHbzRymgZPPk_Ii-9Bz380soA9bcA&sig2=zWghWinQfys3WwYQShnKJg&bvm=bv.51156542,d.b2I

Comment: You are tempting us into madness :) Would you like to describe the effect a bit deeper? (to enlighten and to prevent link rot)

Comment: The OP is talking about nuclear reactions, and absorption. That's not what's being described in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Crossection tables are given for the bulk form of the materials, not for oriented crystals.

Indeed it has been found for the muons in particular, which only interact electromagnetically or weakly, that along the crystal axis there are few losses in the beam momentum. The phenomenon has been proposed for use in high energy muon colliders, bending muon beams by the use of special crystals. See [this proposal](http://beamdocs.fnal.gov/AD/DocDB/0039/003945/001/VS_note_onCrystalAccelerators.pdf) and also [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996NuPhS..51A..90B).

Comment: The OP is talking about nuclear reactions, and absorption.

Comment: @BenCrowell He is NOT specifying nuclear or electromagnetic, crossection tables contain both; the muon channeling shows that as far as charge goes the crystal axis does play a role. If you google you will find also other charge particles affected.http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_042_04_0641.pdf . http://www.sdu.dk/media/bibpdf/Bind%2030-39/Bind/mfm-34-14.pdf   . etc

Comment: The question refers specifically to "absorption" and shadowing by "nuclei."

Comment: @BenCrowell Well, the crossection depends on the crystal axis : if the particle goes through undisturbed on the axis then the crossection is different than if it is off axis, both strong and electromagnetic.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the material has isotropic properties, the *cross sections* are independent of direction.  Cross sections are defined as a function of the material.

However, you are correct that the *absorption rate* will depend on the angle of the beam of the cross sections.  This must be accounted for when calculating the reaction rates, usually in a transport equation.